# Use existing C++ files in Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, java-native-interface, android-sdk-tools

I want to include existing c++ files from here [DetectText](https://github.com/aperrau/DetectText) in my Java code in Android Studio.

Usually (in Linux), I run it by the command 
           `./TextDetection input_file output_file dark_on_light`.

I already compile it with the NDK to obtain a SWT.a file with :

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# static library info
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv_core
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := opencv/lib/libopencv_core.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# static library info
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv_opencv_highgui
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := opencv/lib/libopencv_highgui.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# static library info
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := opencv_imgproc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := opencv/lib/libopencv_imgproc.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := SWT
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := jni/opencv/include/
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += jni/boost/include/boost-1_53
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := FeaturesMain.cpp \
 TextDetection.cpp



include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

But now I need to implement the wrapper and I'm a bit lost. I just want to call the main method from the Java part (which call another method, etc...)

Do I need to change all the method names as something like `Java_com_example_hellojni_HelloJni_stringFromJNI` or just the main method ?

And what about arguments ?

Comment: You'll have to be a lot more specific in describing your problem. _"it doesn't work"_ could mean anything.

Answer (score 0):

As an extremely simple translation from your Linux experience you can build your native code into an executable and run it from Java with Runtime.exec().

You have a significant performance gain if you use in-process JNI module. It may be enough to add just one interface native method and build a shared library that links your static lib (and the OpenCV prebuilt libs).